# Loading modules in a Flex mobile application

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, module, flex-mobile

I am going to write a Flex mobile application which can benefit from loadable modules, but encountered "Modules are not supported for AIR mobile applications." statement [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/modules/ModuleLoader.html).

Is there any workaround to load swf modules (containing UI with some code) in the mobile application developed for iPhone/Android/BlackBerry?

Comment: I don't think anything is possible on iOS as it is against the license terms to load/interpert stuff at runtime.  I'm unclear on specifics there. I thought you could use SWFLoaders on other platforms.  [Don't hold me to that, though].

Answer (score 1):

Did you get any progress on this? I am in the same situation but all I can think of at the moment is to integrate some kind of browser window in the application that loads an swf from the network when needed. Of course leaving the need for a network connection when opening a module. However they say it is not possible to interact with the loaded content, there is the StageWebView:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageWebView.html

What you could do is pass URL parameters. In my case this is not sufficient for my needs, but maybe you can make use of it.